# How to test scss modules

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, sass, jestjs

I am using React with Jest as testing framework and use identity-obj-proxy to get jest to load classNames from `scss` files. This only puts names of requrested class names to tests- it doesn't actually loads scss modules.

Is there way to make a test which will load my entry scss file and simply check if it loads without errors? By loads I mean that it doesn't have any undefined variables, broken imports etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building a separate test suite, that loads scss files, using `sass-true` from npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-true

My test suite lists all files from a given directory and attempts to check consistency of each file with the above.

Comment: why do you need to make this check in scope of unit testing? what if you just make separate `run` script in your `package.json` that will point on special webpack.config with `entry` of your root SCSS?